# How can i uncheck all checkboxes after click button(check selected phones) in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

Here i have added my code below.after Check selected phones button clicked how to uncheck all checked checkboxes pls some one help me out for this .
Expectation:
after button click all checkboxes should unchecked i have added fiddle also help me out

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope,$http) {
 $scope.selectedBrands = [];
  
  $scope.selectBrand = function(selectedphone) {
   // If we deselect the brand
   if ($scope.selectedBrands.indexOf(selectedphone.brandname) === -1) {
     // Deselect all phones of that brand
     angular.forEach($scope.phones, function(phone) {
       if (phone.brandname === selectedphone.brandname) {
         phone.selected = false;
        }
      });
    }
  }
  
  $scope.checkSelectedphones = function() {
        var modelNames = [];
        var jsonArr = [];
        var subModelArr = [];
        var aletrMsg = '';
        angular.forEach($scope.phones, function(phone) {
          if (phone.selected) {
            modelNames.push(phone);
            var found = jsonArr.some(function(el) {
              if (el.model === phone.brandname) {
                el.subModel.push(phone.modelname);
                return true;
              }
            });
    
            if (!found) {
              subModelArr.push(phone.modelname);
              jsonArr.push({
                model: phone.brandname,
    brand :'Nokia',
                subModel: subModelArr,
    city:'Noida',
    
              });
              subModelArr=[];
            }
   
          }
    
        });
  console.log(modelNames.length);
  if(modelNames.length == 0)
  {
  alert(modelNames.length ? aletrMsg : 'No phones selected!');
  }else
  {
        console.log(jsonArr);
        
  
  
      }
 
}

$scope.phones = [{
    id: "986745",
    brandname: "Nokia",
    modelname: "Lumia 735 TS"
  }, {
    id: "896785",
    brandname: "Nokia",
    modelname: "Nokia Asha 230"
  }, {
    id: "546785",
    brandname: "Nokia",
    modelname: "Lumia 510"
  }, {
    id: "144745",
    brandname: "Samsung",
    modelname: "Galaxy Trend 840"
  }, {
    id: "986980",
    brandname: "Samsung",
    modelname: "Galaxy A5"
  }, {
    id: "586980",
    brandname: "Samsung",
    modelname: "Galaxy Note 4 Duos"
  }, {
    id: "986980",
    brandname: "Samsung",
    modelname: "Galaxy A5"
  }, {
    id: "586980",
    brandname: "Samsung",
    modelname: "Galaxy Note Duos"
  }, {
    id: "232980",
    brandname: "Htc",
    modelname: "Htc One X9"
  }, {
    id: "456798",
    brandname: "Htc",
    modelname: "Desire 820"
  }, {
    id: "656798",
    brandname: "Htc",
    modelname: "Desire 810S"
 }];
 
});

myApp.filter('unique', function() {
  return function(collection, keyname) {
    var output = [], 
        keys = [];

    angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
      var key = item[keyname];
      if(keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
        keys.push(key);
        output.push(item);
      }
    });

    return output;
  };
});
```

```css
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
```

```html
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <button ng-click="checkSelectedphones()">
    Check selected phones
  </button>
  
  <div ng-repeat="phone in phones | unique:'brandname'">
    <label>
      <input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="'{{phone.brandname}}'" ng-false-value="''" ng-model="selectedBrands[$index]" ng-change="selectBrand(phone)">  
      {{phone.brandname}}
    </label>
  </div>
  
  <br>
  
  <div ng-repeat="brand in selectedBrands track by $index" ng-if="brand">
    {{brand}}
    <div ng-repeat="phone in phones" ng-if="phone.brandname === brand">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="phone.selected" >  
        {{phone.modelname}}
         
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kLzfru76/16/)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/osw35c14/1/ ?

Comment: sorry bug is there check Nokia u will get 3 checkboxes Lumia 735 TS,Nokia Asha 230,Lumia 510 .here u check  Lumia 735TS,Nokia Asha 230 then click button .then again click Nokia u came to know the bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have the checked state saved in `selectedBrands`, you can just reset the array in the button click like

```
$scope.selectedBrands = [];
```

You will also have to update the `phone.selected` value in the loop

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.selectedBrands = [];

  $scope.selectBrand = function(selectedphone) {
    // If we deselect the brand
    if ($scope.selectedBrands.indexOf(selectedphone.brandname) === -1) {
      // Deselect all phones of that brand
      angular.forEach($scope.phones, function(phone) {
        if (phone.brandname === selectedphone.brandname) {
          phone.selected = false;
        }
      });
    }
  }

  $scope.checkSelectedphones = function() {
    var modelNames = [];
    var jsonArr = [];
    var subModelArr = [];
    var aletrMsg = '';
    angular.forEach($scope.phones, function(phone) {
      if (phone.selected) {
        modelNames.push(phone);
        var found = jsonArr.some(function(el) {
          if (el.model === phone.brandname) {
            el.subModel.push(phone.modelname);
            return true;
          }
        });

        if (!found) {
          subModelArr.push(phone.modelname);
          jsonArr.push({
            model: phone.brandname,
            brand: 'Nokia',
            subModel: subModelArr,
            city: 'Noida',

          });
          subModelArr = [];
        }

      }

      phone.selected = false;
    });
    console.log(modelNames.length);
    if (modelNames.length == 0) {
      alert(modelNames.length ? aletrMsg : 'No phones selected!');
    } else {
      console.log(jsonArr);
    }

    $scope.selectedBrands = [];
  }

  $scope.phones = [{
    id: "986745",
    brandname: "Nokia",
    modelname: "Lumia 735 TS"
  }, {
    id: "896785",
    brandname: "Nokia",
    modelname: "Nokia Asha 230"
  }, {
    id: "546785",
    brandname: "Nokia",
    modelname: "Lumia 510"
  }, {
    id: "144745",
    brandname: "Samsung",
    modelname: "Galaxy Trend 840"
  }, {
    id: "986980",
    brandname: "Samsung",
    modelname: "Galaxy A5"
  }, {
    id: "586980",
    brandname: "Samsung",
    modelname: "Galaxy Note 4 Duos"
  }, {
    id: "986980",
    brandname: "Samsung",
    modelname: "Galaxy A5"
  }, {
    id: "586980",
    brandname: "Samsung",
    modelname: "Galaxy Note Duos"
  }, {
    id: "232980",
    brandname: "Htc",
    modelname: "Htc One X9"
  }, {
    id: "456798",
    brandname: "Htc",
    modelname: "Desire 820"
  }, {
    id: "656798",
    brandname: "Htc",
    modelname: "Desire 810S"
  }];

});

myApp.filter('unique', function() {
  return function(collection, keyname) {
    var output = [],
      keys = [];

    angular.forEach(collection, function(item) {
      var key = item[keyname];
      if (keys.indexOf(key) === -1) {
        keys.push(key);
        output.push(item);
      }
    });

    return output;
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <button ng-click="checkSelectedphones()">
      Check selected phones
    </button>

    <pre>{{selectedBrands}}</pre>

    <div ng-repeat="phone in phones | unique:'brandname'">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="'{{phone.brandname}}'" ng-false-value="''" ng-model="selectedBrands[$index]" ng-change="selectBrand(phone)">{{phone.brandname}}
      </label>
    </div>

    <br>

    <div ng-repeat="brand in selectedBrands track by $index" ng-if="brand">
      {{brand}}
      <div ng-repeat="phone in phones" ng-if="phone.brandname === brand">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="phone.selected">{{phone.modelname}}

        </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: sorry bug is there check Nokia u will get 3 checkboxes Lumia 735 TS,Nokia Asha 230,Lumia 510 .here u check Lumia 735TS,Nokia Asha 230 then click button .then again click Nokia u came to know the bug

Comment: what changes have u made

Comment: @komal `phone.selected = false;` in `angular.forEach($scope.phones, function(phone) {`

Comment: @komal along with `$scope.selectedBrands = [];` in the click handler

Answer (score 0):

Just add `phone.selected = false;` at the end of your forEach and `$scope.selectedBrands = [];` afterwards.

https://jsfiddle.net/bbz9pjhc/1/

PS: The way you are solving your problem doesn't seem to be "the angular way" to do it, so you might think of reworking it. Anyway, hopefully my answer will send you on the right track for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line of Code in your checkselectedPhone() method

```
   for(var i=0;i<$scope.selectedBrands.length;i++)
   {        
         $scope.selectedBrands[i]=false;
    }
```